# Canon 70D turns off after 30 minutes in live view

Tags: live-view, canon-70d

Good day!

My 70D turns off after 30 minutes in live view and I can't do anything about it. I turned off Auto Power Off feature, but it still does it. Any other tips, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's explained on page 217 of [the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300011965/04/eos70d-im6-en.pdf) - seems like Live View shooting will stop after 30 minutes no matter what (it is said that the display turns off without saying anything about the sensor, but most probably the sensor itself turns off too).

I guess it's a safety measure to prevent damage from overheating to the sensor and to save battery.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.tested.com/tech/photography/44445-why-digital-cameras-have-a-30-minute-video-recording-limit/
I think this is connected to this topic somehow. You could use the Live View as a hack for a camera that would record longer so it is limited.

Comment: This is talking about Live View, not video shooting. These are unrelated issues.

Comment: No it isn't as you could use the live video feed for recording on a separate device.

Comment: Why would somebody use a _different_ device to record images from low-res video feed of a live view, when they have a _camera_ that they're trying to use to anyways?

Comment: @scottbb they would a use a video recording device to bypass the 30min limits for video. It makes sense actually for video.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, maybe they are not unrelated. If Canon wants to make sure that nobody will use an external video recorder to bypass the built-in video limit, it is fairly possible.

Comment: @kazanaki actually, that's a fair point. However, such video issues are deep in the realm of _off-topic_ for Photo.SE, so assuming away video is still valid.

Comment: I think that the HDMI-Video-Terminal and the live preview monitor are connected. If you would not make a 30 minutes break for the live view it would not work with the hdmi-terminal either and you could have  a nice 1080/60i video recording on a separate device which would be a hack. This is the actual reason for the 30 minutes limit. Thanks for the thumbs down/up anyways ;)